# Php 7.1 - Empty index operator array

Tags: php, arrays, string, error-handling

As mentioned on http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> Note: As of PHP 7.1.0, applying the empty index operator on a string throws a fatal error. Formerly, the string was silently converted to an array.

Can someone please tell me what does that mean with an example?

How will it affect my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PHP < 7.1:

```
$var = 'somestring';
$var[] = 'a'; # yields array with two elements ['somestring', 'a']
```

In PHP >= 7.1 this yields

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: This sounds right. But [I'm seeing](https://3v4l.org/oaadg#output) that error affect 5.6 and 7.0 as well...?

Comment: Is there any alternative solutions to this? I have some code where I am using this and I can't change the variable name.

Comment: @DevAggarwal: What is your exact problem?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil Hey, Thanks for the help. I am using php 7.0 for now. And this works perfectly fine with it. I'll try php 7.1 later. :)

Comment: @JiriHrazdil : It's throwing fatal error with PHP 5.6.30 just like with PHP 7.1.0, rather than silently converting the string to an array which is supposed to happen if the text from PHP manual is to be believed. It's not happening like the code you mentioned in your answer with PHP 5.6.30

Answer (score 0):

The wording in the docs is a bit weird but what changed in 7.1 is when you have an empty string and then access it that way: [3v4l.org/V5YJa](http://3v4l.org/V5YJa)

Have a look at below code :

```
<?php
$rootbeer = '';
$rootbeer[] = 'T';
?>
```

**Output with PHP 7.1.0 :**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in your_file.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in your_file.php on line 4
```

With **PHP versions** prior to **PHP 7.0.1**, the string gets silently converted to an array without issuing any warning or error.

I hope this would have cleared your doubt.

Comment: I'd say the wording in the docs slides towards being factually incorrect and not just weird.